# How to save yaml generated out of templates for helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed several helm charts in kubernetes out of templates. I can view the the generated yamls using this command:

```
helm install <chart-name> <chart-path> --dry-run --debug
```

What I need is to save yamls generated via this command. Also suggest me a way how i'll be able to get (and write) the yamls while installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helm install <chart-name> <chart-path> --dry-run --debug > temp.yaml`

Further [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

```
helm template --output-dir './' './'
```

helm template will create the YAML files or generate the files you can save those and apply too as per requirement.

```
helm template --output-dir './yaml' './'
```

it will create the directory **YAML** and store all **YAML** output inside that.

last `./` is the path of chart

Comment: Why you specify twice `./`?

Comment: one is for output dir where want to store output and one is for the path to find the yaml files.